# xml <![CData[]]> need browser to decode it

Tags: html, xml, xslt, cdata

i have a problem with my if statement
the browser is not decoding the </tr><tr> 
that is it is not changing line but it is only displaying  </tr><tr> 
on the browser
i have use CData also but it is not working
Can someone please help me

```
<table border="1">
<tr>

<xsl:for-each select="/catalogue/item">

    <td>
    <img src="{img/.}" alt="{img/@alt}" class="imgs-catalogue" title="click for description"/><br/>
    Id: <xsl:value-of select="id/."/><br/>
    Name: <xsl:value-of select="name/."/><br/>
    Type: <xsl:value-of select="type/."/><br/>
    Price: <xsl:value-of select="price/text()"/><br/><br/>
    </td>       

    <xsl:if test="(position() mod 4)=0">
        </tr><tr>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
</tr>
</table>
```

this is the complete xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <?xml-stylesheet  type="text/xsl" href="catalogue.xsl" ?>
 <catalogue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="catalogue.xsd">

<!-- Item 1 -->
<item>
    <id>45</id>
    <name>Ginkgo Plus</name>
    <img alt="Ginkgo Plus">images/catalogueImg/ginkgo.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 575</price>
    <type>Health</type>
    <description>
        A mixture of 3 chineese plant including ginkgo biloba and reishi.
        Many traditional medicines identifies that the leaves of the ginkgo biloba 
        have a positive effect on the circulatory system. The reishi is a champion
        used in chineese and japaneese traditional medicines to protect against 
        heart problems.
    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 2 -->
<item>
    <id>46</id>
    <name>Hand Sanitizer</name>
    <img alt="Hand Sanitizer">images/catalogueImg/hand.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 350</price>
    <type>Beauty</type>
    <description>
        Helps to clean and desinfect perfectly your hands
        wherever you are. This product is enriched in 
        Aloe Vera and honey which perfumes your hand without
        drying them.
    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 3 -->
<item>
    <id>87</id>
    <name>Aloe Vera Gel</name>
    <img alt="Aloe Vera Gel">images/catalogueImg/aloe.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 1300</price>
    <type>Health</type>
    <description>
        First product to have received the label of IASC
        (Conseil International Scientifique de l'Aloe Vera), 
        is a product to be used daily to optimise your health.
        Aloe Vera help to maintain the immune system and helps to 
        strenghen the organism efence.
    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 4 -->
<item>
    <id>74</id>
    <name>Berry Nectar</name>
    <img alt="Berry Nectar">images/catalogueImg/berry.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 1200</price>
    <type>Health</type>
    <description>

    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 5 -->
<item>
    <id>18</id>
    <name>Aloe Sunscreen</name>
    <img alt="Aloe Sunscreen">images/catalogueImg/sun.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 750</price>
    <type>Beauty</type>
    <description>
        This sun care of high protection SPF 30, protects the
        skin from the negative effects of the sun and from
        aging.
    </description>
</item>

    <!-- Item 1 -->
<item>
    <id>45</id>
    <name>Ginkgo Plus</name>
    <img alt="Ginkgo Plus">images/catalogueImg/ginkgo.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 575</price>
    <type>Health</type>
    <description>
        A mixture of 3 chineese plant including ginkgo biloba and reishi.
        Many traditional medicines identifies that the leaves of the ginkgo biloba 
        have a positive effect on the circulatory system. The reishi is a champion
        used in chineese and japaneese traditional medicines to protect against 
        heart problems.
    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 2 -->
<item>
    <id>46</id>
    <name>Hand Sanitizer</name>
    <img alt="Hand Sanitizer">images/catalogueImg/hand.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 350</price>
    <type>Beauty</type>
    <description>
        Helps to clean and desinfect perfectly your hands
        wherever you are. This product is enriched in 
        Aloe Vera and honey which perfumes your hand without
        drying them.
    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 3 -->
<item>
    <id>87</id>
    <name>Aloe Vera Gel</name>
    <img alt="Aloe Vera Gel">images/catalogueImg/aloe.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 1300</price>
    <type>Health</type>
    <description>
        First product to have received the label of IASC
        (Conseil International Scientifique de l'Aloe Vera), 
        is a product to be used daily to optimise your health.
        Aloe Vera help to maintain the immune system and helps to 
        strenghen the organism efence.
    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 4 -->
<item>
    <id>74</id>
    <name>Berry Nectar</name>
    <img alt="Berry Nectar">images/catalogueImg/berry.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 1200</price>
    <type>Health</type>
    <description>

    </description>
</item>

<!-- Item 5 -->
<item>
    <id>18</id>
    <name>Aloe Sunscreen</name>
    <img alt="Aloe Sunscreen">images/catalogueImg/sun.jpg</img>
    <price>MUR 750</price>
    <type>Beauty</type>
    <description>
        This sun care of high protection SPF 30, protects the
        skin from the negative effects of the sun and from
        aging.
    </description>
</item>

</catalogue>
```

and this is the xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalogueStyle.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<title>Catalogue</title>



</head>
<body>  
    <div class="body-wrapper" style="attachment:fixed;">
        <img src="images/header.png"/>
    </div>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="/catalogue/item">

        <td>

        <img src="{img/.}" alt="{img/@alt}" class="imgs-catalogue" title="click for description"/><br/>

        Id: <xsl:value-of select="id/."/><br/>
        Name: <xsl:value-of select="name/."/><br/>
        Type: <xsl:value-of select="type/."/><br/>
        Price: <xsl:value-of select="price/text()"/><br/><br/>
        </td>       

        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 4)=0">
            </tr><tr>
        </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is this an XSLT question? If so, please edit your question and add the input XML document, your XSLT stylesheet and the output you expect. Look here for help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. **Edit**: Please do not link to information (add it here) and do not show code in images (but as text).

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then read http://sscce.org/

Comment: You are approaching this the wrong way. Instead of detecting when to change row an try to insert a row-break, collect the elements you want to comprise the row and surrond them with <tr>...</tr>. Post some example input and your current code if you want someone to comment on it.

Comment: @MathiasMüller thanks for the advice

Comment: @RolfRander i think you have a good point here but in xslt we can't have a variable where the its data keeps on changing. I will try something like you said and see if it work.

Comment: So you want to collect 4 elements on each table row? Can you provide some example input?

Comment: @RolfRander let me post the xml document and the xsl file so that you can better understand it

Comment: I don't see the cdata section in your example, but remember that the whole point of cdata sections is to mark something as being tex, t,_not_ markup. They're a sloppy shorthand alternative to explicitly escaping each instance of `<`, `>`,and `&` in an area. It sounds like you've used one where you sgouldn't have. Some would say you shouldn't use them, period.

Comment: @keshlam i had used the CData with  </tr><tr>
like this this <![CData[</tr><tr>]]> and also used
<![CData[&lt;/tr&ht;&lt;tr&gt;]]>
but when displaying on the browser it is not changing row but simply displaying </tr><tr>

Comment: Do not try to generate XML structure as text. Let XSLT produce it ax real XML. If you're using CDATA sections for anything but scripts, you are usually wrong... and even there it's debatable. Don't try to generate `</tr><tr>` between elements; generate each element within a `<tr></tr>` pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to take is to initially select only the `item` elements that correspond to the first cell of each table row, which can be done like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="/catalogue/item[position() mod 4 = 1]">
```

This effectively corresponds to the rows of your table, so you would create a `tr` element inside the `xsl:for-each`.

Then, you need to select the `item` elements that make up the row, based on the current `item` you have selected, which can be done like this

```
<xsl:variable name="cells" select="current()|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; 4]" />
<xsl:for-each select="$cells">
```

So, it selects the current `item` and the 3 following ones (giving 4 cells per row). For each one, you would output the `td` with the required details.

The only challenge left would be for the last row, when your might have less than 4 items to make up the row. You could create a recursive template here to create empty cells to pad out the row.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="rowsize" select="4" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalogueStyle.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<title>Catalogue</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="body-wrapper" style="attachment:fixed;">
        <img src="images/header.png"/>
    </div>
    <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="/catalogue/item[position() mod $rowsize = 1]">
    <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="cells" select="current()|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $rowsize]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$cells">
        <td>
        <img src="{img/.}" alt="{img/@alt}" class="imgs-catalogue" title="click for description"/><br/>
        Id: <xsl:value-of select="id/."/><br/>
        Name: <xsl:value-of select="name/."/><br/>
        Type: <xsl:value-of select="type/."/><br/>
        Price: <xsl:value-of select="price/text()"/><br/><br/>
        </td>       
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="count($cells) &lt; $rowsize">
            <xsl:call-template name="emptyCells">
                <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$rowsize - count($cells)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="emptyCells">
    <xsl:param name="cells" />
    <xsl:if test="$cells > 0">
        <td></td>
        <xsl:call-template name="emptyCells">
            <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$cells - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have parameterised the `4` to allow you to vary the row size easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to provide a complete solution, but some ideas for an algorithm:

- select all elements matching /catalogue/item into a variable
- in a template, output the 4 first items, wrap these in
- let the template call itself recursively with the rest of the list (excluding the first 4)